# Deleting a file with extension name in JAVA

Tags: java

This is my piece of code. With this I am picking a drive, say F drive in this case. Then on executing the I am trying to delete a file inside that folder, although the file(when correctly entered) is being deleted, yet the delete() is returning false. May I know why so?

```
System.out.println("Enter file to be deleted:");
String del = sc.nextLine(); //give file name as string with extension
File delFile = new File(del); //convert string to file type
for (File fs: listOfFiles) {
    if (fs.getName().compareTo(delFile.getName()) == 0) {
        System.out.println(fs.getName());
        System.out.println("Inside loop");
        boolean dele = fs.delete();
        System.out.println("Successful/unsucceful: " + fs.getName() + "..." + fs.delete());
    } else
        System.out.println("invalid : " + fs.getName());
}
```

Comment: Better use `Files.delete()` instead - that throws an **exception** when deletion goes wrong - and that gives you more insight than "false".

Comment: Just as a sidenote. I would just use `fs.getName().equals(delFile.getName())` instead of your `compareTo`.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is, that you call `fs.delete()` a second time after it was already deleted. Because it doesn't exist anymore, it can't be deleted

Just call the boolean value you've set before:

```
System.out.println("Successful/unsucceful: " + fs.getName() + "..." + dele);
```

Also, just as a sidenote. I would just use `fs.getName().equals(delFile.getName())` instead of your `compareTo`

Comment: Also I would store the return of fs.getName() in a variable instead of calling the function three times.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling `delete` twice. The second time it's false since it got deleted the first time.

Change this

```
System.out.println("Successful/unsucceful: " + fs.getName() + "..." + fs.delete());
```

to

```
System.out.println("Successful/unsucceful: " + fs.getName() + "..." + dele);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I need to enter a file name inorder to delete it. The approach I am taking is through Scanner class I am taking a string and converting it to File type.
String del = sc.nextLine(); //give file name as string with extension
File delFile = new File(del); //convert string to file type
 Is there any other approach to directly take the filename?

Comment: @Shailja As far as I can see from your code you are comparing the name. You don't need to construct a new `File`. Just use the filename from `sc.nextLine` as it is.